# rooted china tablet black screen after boot need help megafeis m700

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, root-access, unbricking

i have a Megafeis m700 tablet i rooted successfully but changed boot animation and now after it boots it goes to a black screen back lighting is still on. when giving command to reboot recovery i simply get the android whit his shell open but no menu just android on his back with red ! please someone help me I've been in front of this computer I've tried everything i can find.